# Is it possible to login as the same user with 3 different environments kde, gnome and unity

Tags: unity, gnome, 12.04, login, kde

Is it possible to login simultaneous as the same user with 3 different environments kde, gnome and unity? Or even more with xfce and lxde?

How can I do that?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 beta, but also have have Ubuntu 11.10 installed.

I ask this question cause I have 3 different users and I would prefer to only have 1.

and i think it would be more easy to handle if i decide to launch the 3 at same time.

Comment: Not without logging out and logging in or a custom .xinitrc that launches three different desktop sessions on login.  If you're okay with a custom .xinitrc you can bind DISPLAY :0.0 to F7, :1.0 to F8, and so on for as many as your box can feasibly run

Answer (score 1):

If you install all three, you should be able to choose which one to use when you login.  This may be disabled by default in 12.04.  Normally, each user will pick a default environment.  Each desktop manager should have a package with a name ending in desktop that will ensure the dependencies are installed.

Running all three simultaneously requires a bit of magic and more than one screen.  The extra screens can be virtual, or additional physical screen.  Not something I would want to try.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the way you have things set up is better.  KDE and gnome don't tend to play well together, and if you're using them with separate users you run less risk of bad configuration bleeding over across managers.  That's my 2 cents, something I wish I would have thought about before trying KDE, because I spend a few hours tracking down all the offenders after that.